# Exception thrown when CryptoStream instance closed

Tags: c#, rijndaelmanaged, cryptostream

I have a DecryptString function that uses the RijndaelManaged Cipher.  It works 99.999% of the time but very occationally it throws an "IndexOutOfRangeException" exception with the message of "Index was outside the bounds of the array." when it tries to close the cryptoStream in the finally block.

When it does stop working it will stop working for a period of 20 minutes or so and then start 
working again with not obvious explination.  One lead I do have is that it only st

```
public string DecryptString(string InputText, string Password)
        {
            //checkParamSupplied("InputText", InputText);
            checkParamSupplied("Password", Password);

            MemoryStream memoryStream = null;
            CryptoStream cryptoStream = null;

            try
            {
                RijndaelManaged RijndaelCipher = new RijndaelManaged();

                byte[] EncryptedData = Convert.FromBase64String(InputText);

                byte[] Salt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Password.Length.ToString());

                PasswordDeriveBytes SecretKey = new PasswordDeriveBytes(Password, Salt);

                // Create a decryptor from the existing SecretKey bytes.
                ICryptoTransform Decryptor = RijndaelCipher.CreateDecryptor(SecretKey.GetBytes(32), SecretKey.GetBytes(16));

                memoryStream = new MemoryStream(EncryptedData);

                // Create a CryptoStream. (always use Read mode for decryption).
                cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, Decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);

                // Since at this point we don't know what the size of decrypted data
                // will be, allocate the buffer long enough to hold EncryptedData;
                // DecryptedData is never longer than EncryptedData.
                byte[] PlainText = new byte[EncryptedData.Length];

                // Start decrypting.
                int DecryptedCount = cryptoStream.Read(PlainText, 0, PlainText.Length);

                // Convert decrypted data into a string. 
                string DecryptedData = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(PlainText, 0, DecryptedCount);

                // Return decrypted string.   
                return DecryptedData;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                //Close both streams.
                memoryStream.Close();
                cryptoStream.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Jonathan - youy question is incomplete...

Comment: Both the text and the code seem to be cut off ...

Comment: Thanks for that, my browser was playing up.  I have added the rest of the code.

Comment: The question is still truncated though

Comment: @Jonathan Stanton - I'm in a similar boat here with random errors arising from the same code. What was the "One lead I do have (truncated)" and did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

One thing I do notice is that you're closing the cryptoStream's underlying stream before you close the cryptoStream itself in your `finally` block - perhaps you should reverse these two statements?

Comment: Probably. Wrapping them in (nested) using blocks also prevents this kind of confusion and errors.